# Is there a reliable reference that shows that Bayes theorem holds for measures, densities, masses, or combinations of these?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, random-variables, bayes-theorem

I am looking for a book or a reliable reference that I can site in a research paper or thesis that shows that Bayes' theorem/rule holds for both probability measures (i.e. events), densities, mass function, and combinations of densities and mass functions (depending on whether the involved random variables are continuous or discrete)? Something like [these notes](http://pwp.gatech.edu/ece-jrom/wp-content/uploads/sites/436/2017/08/16_BayesRVs-su14.pdf) (even more detailed or formal, i.e. it's ok that the book is based on measure theory, provided that it shows these things), but that is a reliable book or research paper that I can cite in a research paper.

Please, do not tell me to derive these things myself, because my knowledge of measure theory is not very good (and I don't have time now to study it), or that I can cite the notes, because I am looking for a reliable book or research paper. Most books I have looked at only present Bayes theorem by considering measures and events.

Comment: The item you link to doesn't seem to mention explicitly the version of the result that says: multiply the prior by the likelihood and then normalize, to get the posterior. Thus suppose you know the marginal probability density function $f_Y(y)$ and the conditional probability density function $f_{X\,\mid\,Y\,=\,y}(x).$ The former is the "prior" density of $Y$ and the latter, as a function of $y,$ not of $x,$ is the "likelihood function": $$L(y) = f_{X\,\mid\,Y\,=\,y}(x).$$ Then $$f_{Y\,\mid\,X\,=\,x}(y) = \text{constant} \times f_Y(y) L(y)$$ where "constant" means not depending on $y. \qquad$

Comment: One advantage of $\quad\uparrow\,\,\,$ this $\,\,\,\uparrow\quad$ way of thinking about it is that it may serve as a reminder of two things: (1) You can sometimes save a lot of work by not thinking about the value of the "constant" until the last step; and (2) you can multiply the prior and the likelihood by any constants that make the arithmetic smooth and efficient and then fix that in the last step. $\qquad$

Comment: As a very simple example: Suppose $\Pr(A) = 1/2,\,\Pr(B)=1/3,\,\Pr(C)=1/6,$ and these are mutually exclusive. And $\Pr(D\mid A) = 1/3\,\Pr(D\mid B)=5/6,\,\Pr(D\mid C)=7/8.$ Then you do this:$$ \begin{align} & \left(\tfrac12,\tfrac13,\tfrac16\right) \times\left( \tfrac 13,\tfrac56, \tfrac78\right) \\ {} \\ \sim {} & (3,2,1) \times (8,20,21) \\ {} \\ \sim {} & (24,40,21) \qquad \text{and } 24+40+21=85. \\ {} \\ \text{Therefore } & \Pr(A\mid D) = \tfrac{24}{85},\, \Pr(B\mid D) = \frac{40}{85},\, \Pr(C\mid D) = \tfrac{21}{85}.   \end{align} $$

Comment: I might begin to think about how to answer your question by recalling the idea of conditional expected value given a sigma-algebra. $\qquad$

Comment: A somewhat less simple example of the above:
$$
\Pr(\Lambda \in A) = \int\limits_A \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha)} \left( \frac \lambda\mu\right)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda/\mu} \left( \frac{d\lambda}\mu\right) \quad \text{for } A\subseteq(0,+\infty)
$$
(the prior is a gamma distribution) and
$$
N\mid \Lambda \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\Lambda).
$$
So the prior is
$$
\text{constant}\times \lambda^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda/\mu}\, d\lambda
$$
where "constant" means not depending on $\lambda$, and the likelihood function is$\,\ldots$

Comment: $$
L(\lambda) = \text{constant} \times \lambda^N e^{-\lambda}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\Pr(\Lambda\in A\mid N) = \int\limits_A \text{constant}\times \lambda^{N+\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda(\frac1\mu+1)}\,d\lambda.
$$
Only after that do we need to think about what this last "constant" is, so we get the posterior distribution:
$$
\frac1{\Gamma(N+\alpha)}\left( \frac{(\mu+1)\lambda}\mu \right)^{N+\alpha-1}e^{-\left(\frac{\mu+1}\mu\right)\lambda} \left( \frac{(\mu+1)\,d\lambda}\mu\right)\quad\text{for }\lambda>0.
$$
Thinking about the "constant" before the last step makes the whole thing more onerous.

Comment: You could probably prove it yourself, in any of the specific cases listed above. Bayes's Theorem is super elementary. The advantage of proving it yourself is that you get to pick both the context and the notation in which you prove it, if you're going to be using it a lot in the rest of your article/thesis/paper/whatever. It seems to me, though, that Bayes's Theorem is perhaps a little overly basic to be spending proof space on in the context of new research? Unless your research is on, like, foundations of probability, advanced-level articles undoubtedly take Bayes's Theorem for granted.

Comment: @RiversMcForge I have no idea how to prove this. If you know how to prove this, feel free to answer this question.

Comment: I'd cite Theorem 1.31 in Schervish, Theory of Statistics.

Comment: @julian Maybe you can explain why you suggest that theorem and you can provide a formal answer, otherwise, my bounty will be lost, and it's a pity.

Answer (score 0):

As announced in the comment, I'd cite Theorem 1.31 in [this](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387945460) book. It says:

> Suppose that $X$ has a parametric
> family $\mathcal{P}_0$ of distributions with parameter space $\Omega$. Suppose that $P_\theta\ll \nu$
> for all $\theta\in\Omega$, and let $f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)$ be the conditional density (with respect to
> v) of X given $\Theta = \theta$. Let $\mu_\Theta$ be the prior distribution of $\Theta$. Let $\mu_{\Theta|X}(\cdot|x)$ denote the conditional distribution of $\Theta$ given $X = x$. Then $\mu_{\Theta|X}\ll\mu_\Theta$,
> a.s. with respect to the marginal of $X$, and the Radon-Nikodym derivative is
> $$
> \frac{d\mu_{\Theta|X}}{d\mu_\Theta}(\theta|x)=\frac{f_{X|\Theta}(x|\theta)}{\int_\Omega f_{X|\Theta}(t|\theta)\,d\mu_\Theta(t)}
> $$
> for those $x$ such that the denominator is neither $0$ nor infinite. The prior
> predictive probability of the set of $x$ values such that the denominator is
> $0$ or infinite is $0$, hence the posterior can be defined arbitrarily for such $x$ values.

In your cases of interest $\nu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: And why does this theorem actually show what I want to see? Maybe explain in your own words.

Comment: As I wrote, you apply the theorem with $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$ and $d\nu=dx$ to get the formula on p.64 of the notes you linked. In the discrete case, $\Omega=\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $\nu$ is the counting measure. The textbook I cited is a highly respected standard reference among statisticians.

Comment: Let me try to understand what that theorem actually says. First, let's look at the formula. The numerator is not a joint but a conditional and the denominator is a marginalization with respect to $t$, so I am not sure how that formula represents the Bayes' theorem/rule, to start with. Can you clarify this first?

Comment: In the notes you've linked $\mu_\Theta$ is assumed to have a density wrt the Lebesgue measure, which is called $f_X$. In other words, $d\mu_\Theta=f_X\,dx$ and you substitute that into the displayed equation and get precisely the formula of p.64.

Comment: The p. 64 of the notes don't mention any measure. So, yeah, if you could explain your answer more in detail, I'd appreciate that!!

Comment: My version is (much) more general than these notes. As I said, the measure there is the Lebesgue measure. Since your question explicitly states that you have little appreciation and knowledge of measure theory, I don’t know how to expand on it.

Comment: Well, my knowledge of measure theory is very small, but I can try to read an explanation that contains measure-theoretic concepts if you are willing to write it, but more in detail!

Answer (score -1):

Bayes' Rule is of course just an application of the definition of conditional probability/ density.  But if you'd like something to refer to, it is stated for general distributions (i.e., encompassing both "densities" and "mass functions") in the introduction (see p. 7 of 2nd edition) of *Bayesian Data Analysis* by Gelman, Carlin, Stern, and Rubin.

Comment: Your OP explicitly says you're *not* looking to prove it, but rather just looking for a reputable book to cite.

Comment: I am saying "that shows", i.e. "that proves". Yes, I am looking for a reputable book that shows it and not that states it. "To show" is typically used as a synonym for "to prove" in mathematics, AFAIK.